# Rails error when using wkhtmltopdf gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the latest Ruby on Rails version and i'm actually trying to generate a PDF with wkhtmltopdf gem.

So, after installing these gems :

```
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

I did this simple test in my console :

```
pdf = PDFKit.new("http://google.fr")
pdf.to_file('google-page.pdf')
```

And i have this following error :

```
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.3.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_amd64: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.9' not found (required by /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.3.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_amd64)
/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.3.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_amd64: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.10' not found (required by /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.3.1/bin/wkhtmltopdf_linux_amd64)
```

I still cannot solve this issue... :(

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Ok, i solved this issue, i have downgraded wkhtmltopdf-binary gem to 0.9.9.3 version and it works for me !

Comment: You could also update to a later version of libc6. This is actually a problem with the libraries you have installed under your OS.